# How can I decode an extrinsic or event dynamically in rust?

Tags: rust, scale-codec, decode

How can I decode an extrinsic or event dynamically in rust? (I want to be able to decode across all parachains)

A lot of the heavy lifting seems to be `frame-metadata` and `scale-info`. There's a [desub](https://github.com/paritytech/desub/blob/master/desub-current/src/value/mod.rs) project that seems like it ought to be able to do this. I've managed to get a `&Type<PortableForm>` based on the v14 metadata but I can't quite see how I can decode it (or alternatively decode it into a JsonValue).

Hmm will try [this](https://github.com/paritytech/desub/blob/852f9539e16a7129ad2be3204d28a17d7e23aae6/desub-current/tests/decode_extrinsics.rs#L99) for extrinsics. Not sure on events?

Comment: Seems that desub requires a byte slice but the extrinsics from a block seem to be OpaqueExtrinsics that are not so keen on showing their bytes...

Comment: `OpaqueExtrinsic` is `Encode`, so it's easy enough to get a byte slice. IIRC extrinsics are typically stored double-encoded (to avoid prescience of a chain's transaction format in lower-level code), so dpending on how desub works you may need to pass it an encoded byte slice. e.g. if you have `xt: OpaqueExtrinsic`, and you want a byte slice you would do either: `&xt.encode()[..]` or `&xt.encode().encode()[..]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding dynamic event decoding, this is something that `cargo-contract` does. It is not easily reusable at the moment but feel free to copy the code and use it for inspiration. Start [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/master/src/cmd/extrinsics/events.rs#L41).

The other alternative at the moment would be to add that functionality to `desub`, which should be relatively straightforward since it already implements the underlying dynamic type decoding.

Eventually there should be a unified crate for dynamically decoding events, possibly as part of `subxt`.

Comment: In case it helps, here also is the code for decondng things in desub-current: https://github.com/paritytech/desub/blob/master/desub-current/src/decoder/decode_value.rs. Definitely going to look at adding this sort of support to subxt.

Comment: libuptest integrates with desub. Not sure if parity has abandoned desub? Development on it seems to been dropping a lot. Link to uptest doc: https://uptest-sc.github.io/code/decode.html